# Indexer stuck at processing Design Config Grid, Customer Grid, and Catalog Search

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, reindex, customer-grid

My indexer always stuck at processing for Design Config Grid, Customer Grid, and Catalog Search

[image]

i already ran `php bin/magento indexer:reset` , but when the cron indexer run the result still the same, i tried to invalid all the indexer state in the database 
`update indexer_state set status = 'invalid'` 
but the result still the same.

When i checked the cron_schedule table in my database, the job code for `indexer_reindex_all_invalid` is always too late for the schedule:
[image]